# Preview not appearing in xml file of Map Activity(Android Studio v2.1.1; SDK v25; using API 21)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

While creating a Map Activity on Android Studio, preview for the xml code is not appearing.Also, the emulator is not appearing. The preview window is instead blank and shows the message 'Exception raised during rendering: com/android/util/PropertiesMap'(see image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0jhw.png

Also, when I click to see details, it opens the Stack Trace: (see image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGsCR.png

Please help!

Comment: What if you upgrade Android  Studio to 2.3?

Comment: Build  -> Clean Project then Build -> Rebuild Project